# Logical Duplicates in mysql

Tags: mysql

My table is like below :

```
city1 city 2 distance flag
A      B      200      Y
C      D      300      N
B      A      200      N
```

My requirement is to check if A & B (or B & A) exists with flag=Y.

Any help will be highly useful

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Strawberry Off course I tried but not able to figure out and that's the reason I came here.

Comment: @Monty could you post what you've tried so far in your question?

Comment: @TBotV63 and straberry : Thanks but I got the answer from Darshan. Please if you know the answer then you should help people instead of wasting time. What does it matter to you if I tried it or not. Internet is free and so does stack overflow.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use `SELF JOIN` to do this, e.g.:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `table` t1 JOIN `table` t2
ON t1.city1 = t2.city2 AND t1.city2 = t2.city1 AND t1.flag = t2.flag
WHERE t1.flag = 'Y';
```

Here's the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/234c8c/4/0)**.

Comment: Hi M. Mehta, could you please tell me what is the difference between SELF JOIN and `select * from table1 where city1= A OR city1= B AND flag=Y`. Thanks in advance

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers self join is joining the table to self (read it [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-self-join/)) whereas the above query returns all the records with either `city1=A` or `city2=B` so they both are completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Simple Concatenation and Conditional check will work out as shown in below

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable(
 city1 VARCHAR(MAX),
 city2 VARCHAR(MAX), distance int, flag VARCHAR(1))
 INSERT INTO #TempTable (city1, city2, distance,flag)
  VALUES ('A',   'B',    200,  'Y'), 
  ('C',   'D',    300,  'N'), 
  ('B',   'A',    200,    'N'),
  ('B',   'A',    2100,    'Y')

  SELECT * FROM #TempTable
  WHERE (city1+City2='AB' AND Flag='Y') OR (city1+City2='BA' AND Flag='Y')
```